# Should I download the jars listed in compile dependencies in mvnrepository.com website?

Tags: java, json, xml, maven

I am working on a web services project. I started with some tutorials that recommended XML. Now I am moving to use JSON. I learned that I need this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/1.19.2  But I found that "compile dependencies" for the above jar. Should I download all those as well? I have used maven in my project before, but mostly I used it without an understanding. So now your answers and directions will help me learn it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below dependency under dependency tag in your project pom.xml , that jar will automatically will be download and added to your class path , then you can use that jar classes in your code .

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
     <version>1.19.2</version>
  </dependency>
```